# Logging at Gevent application

Tags: python, gevent

I'm trying to use standard Python logging module alongside with gevent. I have monkey patched threading and I expect logging to work with my app:

```
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
fh = logging.FileHandler('E:\\spam.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)

def foo():
    logger.debug('Running in foo')
    gevent.sleep(0)
    logger.debug('Explicit context switch to foo again')

def bar():
    logger.debug('Explicit context to bar')
    gevent.sleep(0)
    logger.debug('Implicit context switch back to bar')


gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(foo),
    gevent.spawn(bar),
])
```

Unfortunately E:\spam.log is empty and I can see no output to the console. It seems that either I haven't configured logging properly or gevent does not support it at all (which I don't believe, because gevent documentation says that it [does](http://learn-gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gevent.html#examples)). So, how can I log at gevent app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't configured it correctly. You need to set the `DEBUG` level on the logger rather than the handler, otherwise the logger's default level (`WARNING`) causes your debug messages to be dropped. Try doing a

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

and it should work.